# Why isn't emacs-lisp-mode derived from lisp-mode?

Tags: major-mode, derived-mode

Just out of curiosity, why isn't `emacs-lisp-mode` derived from `lisp-mode`? Instead, both are derived from `prog-mode`.

It seems to me that there is a natural hierarchical relationship that should exist. Is the current situation simply a case of historical accident, or is there a good reason that `emacs-lisp-mode` should not derived from `lisp-mode`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `lisp-mode` is actually meant to be the major mode for Common-Lisp.  Emacs-Lisp and Common-Lisp are closely related but neither is a superset of the other, so they should both derive from the same parent mode but not from each-other.

We could probably introduce a `lispish-mode` as a parent of all major modes for Lisp-like languages, but I'm not completely sure how much they could/should share (should it accomodate Scheme as well?  Clojure?)

Comment: Interesting. It does make it difficult to make some Lisp-specific modifications, however. For example, if I want to use `prettify-symbols-mode` for all Lisps to display `lambda` as the single Greek letter, what hook should I add this functionality to? If I add it to `prog-mode-hook`, it will affect non-Lisp languages too (which is not a big deal).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding it to both `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` and `lisp-mode-hook`.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: I'd say using `prettify-symbols-mode` to display `lambda` as an actual lambda makes sense for languages that use `lambda`, this includes several but not all lisps (for example Clojure and Arc don't use lambda) and also includes some other languages, such as Python.

Comment: Note that `prettify-symbols-mode` is a *global* minor mode.  So it's something that gets enabled and applies to *all* modes at the same time.  Which symbols get prettified is specified independently by each major mode.